# Gitflow - who tests master branch and who tests release branch

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I want to propose Gitflow for our new web application. We have QA environment where product acceptance testing is done before release. I want to know which branch should be deployed to QA - release branch or master? Which branch should be deployed to production? If we deploy and test the release branch and then merge it back to master who will test master?

Answer (score 5):

The `release` branch is meant to be sent through QA validation and deployment process.

So your `release` branch would be sent to QA environment.  Once validation is complete, `release` branch would be deployed.  Once deployment is successful, `release` branch would be merged into `master`.

`master` should always represent the code that is **currently** running on production.  That way if you needed to issue a hotfix while the current `release` branch is being validated, you could branch off of `master`.  Or if for some reason you needed to redeploy a production instance you would deploy `master`.

Answer (score 0):

> want to know which branch should be deployed to QA - release branch or master?

I would argue `release`: QA should test what comes *before* what you end up deploying.

> Which branch should be deployed to production?

`master`, the one where you tag the release with its name.

Comment: What is there are issues when we merge release back to master? Doesn't someone need to test master after release branch has been merged to make sure merge was ok

Comment: @smarinova1 normally no: the release HEAD should replace/override what was in master.

Comment: normally during merging there are conflicts that need to be resolved manually or automatically. But to me it is scary to just rely on a merge logic that master will be replaced by release. Unless there is a special git command to just say replace master with release

Comment: @smarinova1 It is just you don't do any evolution on master since the last release. So the next one simply come and override the previous one.